# Incoming connection on port 80 to webserver application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I made a Java web application running on tomcat, what I'm trying to do now is letting people outside my net acceding my application.
I've read lot of guides and I understood I need to forward incoming traffic on port 80 to the raspberry hosting it (listening on port 8080).

What I did was going to the router panel and make a port forwarding with the following parameters:

[image: port forwarding]

- Are all the parameters right?
- What should i put in the remote IP address?
- What I meant to do is redirecting request on port 80 to local port 8080 on which the raspberry is listening (if tomcat is listening to port 8080 if i write something like ip/webappname will I access my application?)

By the way, with the following settings, if I write my "outside" ip as url, I get prompted with a user\password form. I tried to make some tcpdump to try to understand if it's raspberry or router related, but I got tons of packets and couldn't find a way out, what could it be? Thanks.

Comment: On the question regarding the user\password prompt, I found it to be something router related, as I access an internal ip with an external address. From outside the net I get 404 resources not found is I write ip/appName in the url bar

Comment: I guess you would need Apache HTTP server as well in front of Tomcat. Apache HTTP will listen on 80 and route the traffic to Tomcat instance. In router panel - you have to configure rule for Apache HTTP. Local IP address should be your Apache HTTPD on port 80.